# How to create a Pivot table by range of age instead of age with Python

Tags: python, pivot, range

My table includes the age of customers (column "age") and the category of products clients purchase (column "categ")

I would like to create a pivot table with the category in function of the age.

The following code works fine :

```
Python
 - X = "categ"
 - Y= "age"
 - cont = table_pct[[X,Y]].pivot_table(index=X,columns=Y,aggfunc=len,margins=True,margins_name="Total")
 - cont
```

However, as there are too many different ages, I would like to do the same for ranges of ages instead of ages.

So I created ranges of ages :

```
 - table_pct['tranche_age']=pd.cut(table_pct.age, range(10, 110, 6), right=False)
 - table_pct.head(10)
```

But my first code does not work for the ranges of ages :

```
 - X = "categ" 
 - Y= "tranche_age"
 - cont = table_pct[[X,Y]].pivot_table(index=X,columns=Y,aggfunc=len,margins=True,margins_name="Total")
   cont
```

**I encounter the following error : *TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category***

Thank you for your help !